# Sonarqube Postgres Queries - Add users to groups

Tags: sonarqube

Does anyone know the specific postgres query in the sonar DB to add a sonar-user to the sonar-administrators role?

Answer (score 0):

sonar=# INSERT INTO groups_users (group_uuid, user_uuid) VALUES ('place group_uuid here', 'place user_uuid here');